# Angular and express with Azure DevOps

Tags: angular, angularjs, express, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

i have **Angular** in **Azure Devops Build** and **Release Pipeline** which puts it on a **Azure Web app**.
I have **Express** with **MongoDB** as Backend, but where would be the best position to put this on? Another **Azure Web App** or where?

I think it would be nice to also include those into the build and release pipeline in azure devops, i would have 2 artefacts which i could then use in the release pipeline.

I think i am just a little confused and need a pointer in the right direction :)